# Aligning columns headings on custom listview checkboxes

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, tablelayout

I'm using a tablelayout where each row has a number of checkboxes, and am using a custom adapter. The columns do expand evenly across the screen.  On the parent layout I also have a series of "check/uncheck all" type checkboxes and they line up perfectly with the listview checkboxes.  My issue is that I can't get column headings for the checkboxes to line up with the columns.  They have a creep, either too much or too little, let alone working across both phone and tablet devices.  My suspicion is that the problem may be caused by the text associated with the leftmost checkboxs, the only ones that have any text associated with them.

This is the xml for the check/uncheck all checkboxes and lines up fine.

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/light_blue"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:width="60dp"
                android:background="@color/light_blue"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:text="Ck all"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBoxI"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/light_blue"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBoxII"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/light_blue"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />
```

etc.

This is for column headings and does not line up.

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/light_blue"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:width="60dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@color/light_blue"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/light_blue"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="I"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/light_blue"
                android:text="I"/>
```

etc

This is another attempt that also does not line up.

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/light_blue"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:width="60dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text=""
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@color/light_blue"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/keycode"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/light_blue"
                android:text="I"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/light_blue"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:text="II"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
```

etc.

I've tried many different combinations of text alignment, and even tried to force the column widths which of course wouldn't work across devices.  I've spent all day on this and still have no clue.  Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it was my stupidity.  I had forgotten that I had left LinearLayouts around the table rows as I was cutting and pasting.  After removing those Linearlayouts things lined up as expected.  I did have to give the first column a textsize parm though, otherwise the variable width of the text associated with the leftmost checkbox messed up the alignment of the rest of the columns.  I just had to make the textsize larger than any of the text in that column.